# Move cache_fluid folder

Tags: blend-files

I have my `.blend` file synchronized to the cloud, but the `cache_fluid` folder is getting very big, and I don't need it in the synchronized folder. Is there a way to move the folder somewhere else and get Blender to use it, without creating a new `cache_fluid` folder, in its new location?

Comment: Isn't this shown under the _Fluid_ panel...

Comment: That is set to tmp/cache_fluid but blender is saving them in a folder next to the .blend files

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**. You can change the path in *Physics > Fluid* with the domain object selected:

[image]